# How to locate where is this mentioned in bash

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I removed rvm but now every time I do `ls` I get this message:

```
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/initialize: No such file or directory
```

It looks like it's still calling it from somewhere but can't seem to find from where. How can I see where it is being called?

Answer (score 2):

Knowing the name of the file that is being called makes it easier.

Create the file `/usr/local/rvm/scripts/initialize` (you might have to create the intermediate directories), and give it the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec >>/tmp/trace.log
echo $0 Invoked.
P=$$
while (( P > 1 )); do
  printf '%s %s\n' "$(stat -c%N /proc/$P/cwd)" "$(ps -p $P -ocmd=)"
  P=($(ps -p $P -oppid= ) ) || exit
done
```

Make it world-executable (`chmod a+x /usr/local/rvm/scripts/initialize`). Then wait for the trace file to show up. It will contain the working directory and command line for each process in the tree leading to `initialize`

Answer (score 1):

Adding "set -x" as the line after #!/bin/bash in all the relevant bash scripts might help.

You can also try "strace " as it will show system calls such as file opens and stderr/stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Check through your bash initialization files:

```
grep rvm ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash_login \ 
  /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile
```

Some of the files under your `$HOME` directory might not exist which will give you an error message about no such file but you can safely ignore that.